# Solr date field format

Tags: solr

I'm a little confused on the proper format for the solr date fieldtype.  When importing from a mySQL database does it need to be in this format?

```
1995-12-31T23:59:59Z
```

In my database the date and time fields are in different columns.  Right now my query looks like this.

```
SELECT eb.eventID, concat(CAST(e.startDate AS CHAR),'T ',CAST(e.startTime as CHAR),'Z')
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm using Solr 3.5 btw.  I'm under the impression there was a datetime fieldtype that was deprecated from a previous version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does need to be in that format if you use the Solr "DateField" type:
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html

I don't know the proper way to format dates in MySQL but you do want to make sure that the date is in the format yyyy-mm-dd and the time in the format HH:mi:ss.